# Cloudant - search index for free text search - collecting values into String VS Array

Tags: lucene, couchdb, cloudant, bigcouch

Considering documents like

```
{ firstName: "Jack", lastName: "Smith"}
```

and

```
{firstName: "Simon", lastName"Jackson"}
```

to build up a search index for "free-text" - I can do either:

```
for(var key in doc)
  index("default", doc[key], {"store":true});
//e.g. resulting field = default:["Jack", "Smith"]
```

OR

```
var indexString = "";
for(var key in doc)
  indexString += " " + doc[key];

index("default", indexString, {"store":true}); 
//e.g. resulting field = default:"Jack Smith"
```

Is there are performance / search quality difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are using standard analyzer, there is no any performance difference between indexing "Jack Smith", and ["Jack", "Smith"]. The Standard analyzer will break "Jack Smith" into "Jack", "Smith" anyways.

About search quality, it depends if you want to search for the whole phrase: "Jack Smith". Both these two options will allow you to search for "Jack" or "Smith" individual queries, but only the last option will allow you to search for a phrase "Jack Smith".